# how to do this right in nodejs? parallel keepalive http request to the same website

Tags: node.js, http, parallel-processing, web-scraping, web-crawler

i'm writing a nodejs based web scraping tool and i managed to finish the job, but i want to know if there's a more efficient way to do that and how

the problem is like:

- to speed up the scraping, i need to generate **N**-parallel http connection (keep-alive as default in http.request or request) to a website
- i also have this total **M**-requests(tasks) to do before completing the scraping
- **M>>N**, actually **M** can be infinite
- use keep-alive connection is a must in my job, otherwise i might get kicked off by the target website

my current solution is:

- initialize **M** http.request/request, which is a one-to-one mapping from **M**-requests(tasks)
- set up **http.globalAgent.maxSockets = N**
- let the http.globalAgent manage the connection pool

that did the job, no leak, no failed requests, **N** concurrent http connection, viola.
the problem is that obviously it allocate huge amount of memory to build **M** http.request at the beginning.

so i'm thinking of:

- still let http.request manage the connection pool, keep-alive
- build a task generator, say **T**, having method **T**.*fetchTask()*
- generate **N** requests at the beginning, fire them
- once a certain request **R** is completed, do *task=**T**.fetchTask()* and feed *task* to **R**, reuse the connection, keep-alive

but how? thanks all.

Comment: you might want to consider using phantomjs and node-phantom

Comment: hi Josh, thanks but that's not the issue here. i'm not trying to simulate a browser action. i'm focusing on low-level only.